# Is it right to have alternate hreflang tags referencing the same pages in other languages for all pages of the website?

Tags: seo, internationalization, rel-alternate

For an E-Commerce, is it right to have alternate tags referencing the same pages (in other languages obviously) for all pages of the website?

I'll explain better, a site with alternate tag in homepage, very simple example:

```
<link rel="alternate" href="www.example.com" hreflang="xx-xx"/>
```

and another page of the same site:

```
<link rel="alternate" href="www.example.com/categories" hreflang="xx-xx"/>
```

with the products list:

```
<link rel="alternate" href="www.example.com/categories/ab" hreflang="xx-xx"/>
```

and finally the product:

```
<link rel="alternate" href="www.example.com/categories/ab/prod_code" hreflang="xx-xx"/>
```

Is it right for SEO to build every single link in every single page in a site, for all the sites?
In practice, put the link of the page that you are viewing currently, in every languages for every domain.

Comment: I don’t understand. To which pages does an English page link to with `alternate`+`hreflang`? To its Spanish translation? To itself? To all English pages of the site? To all pages, English and Spanish, of the whole site? -- I think it would help if you [edit] your question to include an example showing the current page URL (and its language) and all of its `link` elements with `alternate`+`hreflang` (and the language codes).

Answer (score 1):

I think you do want to put several hreflang tags on each of your pages, if you have the page in several alternate languages. This will help Google understand and crawl your site.

> The hreflang attribute on each page should include a reference to
>   itself as well as to all the pages that serve as alternates for it. If
>   your Spanish website sells Iberian ham to customers in Spain, France,
>   and Portugal only, the hreflang attributes for your homepage might
>   look like this:
>
> ```
> <link rel="alternate" href="example.com" hreflang="es-es" />
> <link rel="alternate" href="example.com/fr/" hreflang="fr-fr" />
> <link rel="alternate" href="example.com/pt/" hreflang="pt-pt" />
> ```

source: https://moz.com/learn/seo/hreflang-tag

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I meant another thing...is it right to have the alternate tag on each page of the site, with "href="www.example.com/my/page/on/the/site"? That is, the href is showing the current url of the page, regardless of the page which is

Comment: @Chris_Zer that's what they say to do in the yellow area. Include a reference to **itself** as well as to all the other pages. Isn't that what you are asking about?!